# How would i change the difficulty of my game?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm in the process of creating my pinball game - and i feel the game is a bit bland, because it's a prototype i have only set 4 bumpers in the whole game, and each bumper giving 10,000 points. I am wondering how i can add a difficulty setting to easy medium and hard.

easy giving 10,000 per hit
medium giving 5,000 per hit
and hard giving 2,500 per hit.

This is my code associated with the scoring system and the bumpers (For testing purposes i have set the event handler as a click - but i will be changing it to when the ball touches it to allow the points and rebound in the opposite direction).

```
    for(var i=0;i<bumpersArray.length;i++){
    bumpersArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,add_score);
}

    function add_score(e:MouseEvent){
    myScore.add(10000);
}
```

I would assume you would need an if statement linked to a button created after you push start so something like

```
if (easy_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, easyGame))
{

        for(var i=0;i<bumpersArray.length;i++){
        bumpersArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,add_score);
    }

        function add_score(e:MouseEvent){
        myScore.add(10000);
    }
}
```

That's just a wild guess - but yes. Thank You. :)

Comment: How about not hard coding the values and setting the appropriate values based on the setting.

Comment: @BobbyDigital could you give me an example of how i should set out the values? Sorry, i'm still in the beginners of flash and there's much i still need to know and understand.

Comment: It's more of a concept issue. It you had a variable called `score` when the player chooses the level you would set that variable to the appropriate amount. That way there's no if/then-s. Same code works for all levels with no changes.

Comment: @BobbyDigital oh okay, i kind of understand that - thanks for your response :)

Comment: Also, it's pretty hard to change the difficulty on pinball game at all, you probably can reduce available times for combos maybe, or increase ball velocity to shorten reaction time required to hit the ball, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple,

step 1: you just define the `scoreIterator` value based on the level like so:

```
var scoreIterator:Number;

switch (difficulty) {
case "easy" :
    scoreIterator = 10000;
    break;
case "medium" :
    scoreIterator = 5000;
    break;
case "hard" :
    scoreIterator = 2500;
    break;
default :
    break;
}
```

Then your function becomes this:

```
if (easy_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, easyGame))
{

    for(var i=0;i<bumpersArray.length;i++){
        bumpersArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,add_score);
    }

    function add_score(e:MouseEvent){
        myScore.add(scoreIterator);      //<-- this is now dynamic
    }
}
```